# Updating choices without breaking the List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have a Sharepoint List which includes a list of research areas. We have entered the values (11 for the primary level, just over 100 for the secondary level), but some have been updated.

Currently, if we change the Choice it doesn't then change all the entries that had that choice selected. For example, if the Choice was "A00 - Data infrastructure" and the name has changed to "A00 - Data infrastructure and networks" all entries with "A00 - Data infrastructure" keep that text and go white as it is no longer a choice.

Is there any way I can get all existing entries with A00 to change to the updated choice?

I am using Sharepoint Online with the modern interface, through an organisational license (which might mean some features are disabled)

Comment: As per my knowledge it is by default in a SharePoint Online list. You can update those existing entries in batch using PowerShell/Api/Power Automate flow.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Update-a-Choice-column-in-a-Sharepoint-List-with-a-selected/td-p/410339

Yes the choices can be updated, please try this:

- Set the Items property of your dropdown to the Choices of your SharePoint List.

```
Choices('YourList.YourColumn')
```

- Use the Patch function to update the Choice column in your SharePoint List with the selected dropdown option.

```
Patch('YourList', ThisItem, {YourColumn: {Value: Dropdown1.Selected.Value}})
```

- Set the Default property of your dropdown to `ThisItem.YourColumn.Value` so that the choice in the gallery doesn’t snap back to the first choice when the corresponding SharePoint List is updated.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint/scenarios-choice-to-lookup